# can you use axis scale breaks with plotly.js?

Tags: plotly.js

Does anyone know if it's possible to create an axis/scale "break" with **plotly.js specifically**, such as is being done in these canvas.js examples?

https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/bar-chart-axis-scale-break/

https://canvasjs.com/jsp-charts/chart-axis-scale-bre

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called `rangebreaks` in plotly, see https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-rangebreaks. It is currently only available for date axes.